# UserProfile Object in DbSet I set up in SimpleMembershipProvider not populating

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using SimpleMembershipProvider in a MVC app.  The name of my UserProfile table is 'Employees'.
Here is the line of code where I initialize the table==> `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("PcsWebDB", "Employees", "IdNumber", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);`

After it was created and I logged in (thus creating a user on the system) I added fields to the table via SQL Modify Table Command then populated with inserts.  Followed by updating my model with the new fields (and double and triple checking they match the table).

My problem is that Employees is always NULL when I try to reference it.  Here is my Context==>

```
public class PcsWebDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    public PcsWebDB()
    {
        Employees = Set<Employee>();
    }
```

I can see data in company and patients.  Transactions show the following: Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results" as its an empty table that is what I would expect.  But even though there is data in the Employees table the Employees object is always null .  The fact that it is NULL instead of just empty leads me to believe that it's not even getting initialized correctly. I suspect it may have something to do with SimpleMembership.  I can't seem to find anything on the web regarding this.

So my question is two fold.  One, any good tools for troubleshooting Entity Framework for a problem like this (as it's obviously a behind the scenes issue) and two Why am I getting a Null when I know there is data?

All help is MUCH appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what this ended up being: In the employee table there were two fields that had 'id' in the name.  And one of them had a NULL value.  Even though I had annotated my primary key I think EF was getting confused and was trying to use the NULL value one.  Once I got ride of the field (I realized I really didn't need it) and had no NULL in a field with id in it... It worked!